# Does $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{\text{Sum of permutations of digits of }n}$ converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, permutations, decimal-expansion

Hopefully the following chart explains some things:
$$\begin{array}{|l|l|} \hline
n & \frac{1}{\text{Sum of permutations of digits of }n} \\ \hline
1 & \frac{1}{1} \\ \hline
2 & \frac{1}{2} \\ \hline
3 & \frac{1}{3} \\ \hline
10 & \frac{1}{10+01} \\ \hline
11 & \frac{1}{11+11} \\ \hline
172 & \frac{1}{172+127+271+217+712+721} \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

I know the harmonic series diverges but I can't compare it to that because it is bigger after $n=9$. How can I test whether or not it converges?

This problem is in base $10$ but it would be interesting to see it generalized to all bases.

Comment: What's the downvote for?

Comment: For information, if we consider duplicated integer as the same digit, the series does seem to converge still, to a value of approx 4.7472, when computed up to n=50.000

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's discuss the sum of all digit permutations of the numbers that have $n$ digits. There are $n!$ premutations, meaning that the denominator is AT LEAST $n!$. If we write the sum this way:
\begin{equation}
\sum^{\infty}_{n=1,n-number\ of\ digits}\frac{1}{sum\ of\ permutations}\leq \sum^{\infty}_{n=1,n-number\ of\ digits}\frac{1}{n!}
\end{equation}
There are at most $10^n$ (not precisely, but does not affect convergence) numbers that have $n$ digits, meaning:
\begin{equation}
\sum^{\infty}_{n=1,n-number\ of\ digits}\frac{1}{n!}\leq \sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{10^n}{n!}
\end{equation}
The last sum converges (easily provable by some of the criteria), meaning that your sum converges too. The key was to think in terms of number of digits rather than the numbers themselves.

Comment: The number of permutations of an $n$-digit number is less than $n!$, if the number has repeated digits. E.g., the number of digit permutations of the three-digit number $777$ is one, not six. And since all $n$-digit numbers for $n\ge11$ have repeated digits, $n!$ is a serious overestimate for the number of digit permutations.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, the OP gave an example where the number $11$ has two permutations, they consider the digits to be different, so it is exactly $n!$

Comment: @Thomas, you're right. But that's crazy.

Comment: @GerryMyerson agreed, the question would be much more interesting (I think) by considering repeating digits as unique (as you did).

Comment: @GerryMyerson At first, I thought that was the case. I agree on that one, too. This one seems far easier to solve because of this n! trick.

Answer (score 6):

Let $\mathcal{W}_d = \{1, \ldots, 9\} \times \{0, \ldots, 9\}^{d-1}$ denote the set of all strings for the $d$-digit decimal expressions. If we denote OP's sum by $S$, then

\begin{align*}
S
&= \sum_{d=1}^{\infty} \sum_{(a_1,\ldots,a_d) \in \mathcal{W}_d} \frac{1}{(d-1)!(\underbrace{11\ldots11}_{d})(a_1 + \cdots + a_d)} \\
&= \sum_{d=1}^{\infty} \frac{9}{(d-1)!(10^d - 1)} \sum_{(a_1,\ldots,a_d) \in \mathcal{W}_d} \frac{1}{a_1 + \cdots + a_d}.
\end{align*}

Clearly $|\mathcal{W}_d| = 9 \cdot 10^{d-1}$, and so, $S$ is bounded by

$$ S \leq \sum_{d=1}^{\infty} \frac{9}{(d-1)!(10^d - 1)} |\mathcal{W}_d| < \infty. $$

Comment: I'm not sure where your $(d-1)!$ comes from. It's not the number of permutations of a $d$-digit number; that could be a lot less. The number of permutations of the three-digit number $777$, for example, is just one.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, OP *does distinguish* permuted numbers from the original one, even if the permuted one happens to be identical to the original number. OP clearly demonstrated this in the case $n=11$, where the transposition of $11$ (via switching the 10's digit and 1's digit) is considered distinct from the original $11$ and consequently the resulting fraction is $\frac{1}{11+11}$.

Comment: I know, I already admitted it in comments on the other answer.